# VB.Net Code Formatter Like perltidy for perl

Tags: vb.net, code-formatting

Good day!

Are there any code formatter for vb.net that can automate code formatting? 
like perl's perltidy.

I know I can do it manually but the class that I'm working on is getting bigger and I need a constant formatting for all.  And if possible, free.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at CodeRush?

Comment: Is not free. thanks tho :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have plenty of options for that:

- [CodeMaid](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) (free extension)
- [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (trial)
- [CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush/) (trial)

Or the built-in feature of Visual Studio:

Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>)

and many more. Just use your favorite search engine for more.